# Windows Phone Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone, pivot

I am new to windows phone. I am trying to make pivot of questions . I want to add a text block and 2 radio buttons on each pivot item . I managed to add the textbook but didn't know how to add radio buttons.

```
var count = i + 1;
var textblok = new TextBlock { Text = o["questions"][i]["question"].ToString(), FontSize = 20,Width=450};
textblok.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
quizPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem { Name="question"+count, Header = "Question " + count, Content = textblok,});
```

after adding container

```
   for (var i = 0; i < Globals.quizcount; i++) 
                {
                    var count = i + 1;
                    var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
                    var textblok = new TextBlock { Text = o["questions"][i]["question"].ToString(), FontSize = 20,Width=450};
                    textblok.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    stackpanel.Children.Add(textblok);
                    var radio = new RadioButton { Name = "useransYes", Content = "Yes" };
                    stackpanel.Children.Add(radio);
                    var radio1 = new RadioButton { Name = "useransNo", Content = "No" };
                    stackpanel.Children.Add(radio1);

                    //, HorizontalAlignment = "Left", Margin = "66,317,0,0", VerticalAlignment = "Top
                    quizPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem { Name = "question" + count, Header = "Question " + count, Content = stackpanel });
                    quesId.Text = o["questions"][i]["_id"].ToString();
                }
```

2nd i want to know how to get all the pivot items i mean the contents in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a container control to add multiple UI controls to single `PivotItem`. For example using `StackPanel` as container :

```
//create the container
var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
//create textblock
var textblok = new TextBlock { Text = o["questions"][i]["question"].ToString(), FontSize = 20,Width=450};
textblok.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
//add to container
stackpanel.Children.Add(textblok);
//create radiobutton
var radiobutton = new RadioButton{Content = "Radio Button content"}
//add to container
stackpanel.Children.Add(radiobutton);
//add the container as content of pivot item
quizPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem { Name="question"+count, Header = "Question " + count, Content = stackpanel,});
```

Anyway, there is another way around to accomplish this with much cleaner approach. Avoid creating UI controls from code by using data-binding and templating pivot item.

Comment: Thanks @har07. it adds radio button to pivot item but causes a prob. i have currently 4 pivot items it just displays 1.

Comment: you have 4 pivot items, but can only see one pivot item? sounds very weird problem (or I misunderstand the problem). How you know it is actually 4?

Comment: i am adding 4 different questions to pivot item.each question in 1 pivot item.

Comment: I have updated my question. Basically i am creating pivot items dynamically with a single question in it.

Comment: Yes I can see that. So user will swipe the pivot to see next question. Anyway, I can't see anything wrong with the code, it should correctly added new pivot item next to last existing pivot item.

Comment: issue is the name of the radio buttons. can you please tell me how to name these ??

Comment: need 1 more favor please. as these are dynamic i am having trouble in getting the values after last question answered. can u please help ???

Comment: hi @nOmi, it is better for everyone if you open new question regarding that latest trouble. Post your latest code and explain the problem clearly so I and other members around SO can understand it better. Ideally, **one post** should contains no more than **one specific question**. That will make the post cleaner and readable for future visitors. Remember that we are not only solving your problem here, but also trying to build knowledge-base that hopefully useful for others having similar problem. Thank you

Comment: ok got it. i have posted a new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281045/dynamic-pivot-item-contents-values 
Please take a look. Thanks