# Dynamic Pivot item contents values

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivot

I am new to pivot and wp8. i want to access some content's values from dynamic pivot items. here are my dynamic pivot items

```
for (var i = 0; i < Globals.quizcount; i++)
                {
                    var count = i + 1;
                    if (count == Globals.quizcount)
                    {

                        var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
                        var textblok = new TextBlock { Text = o["questions"][i]["question"].ToString(), FontSize = 20, Width = 450 };
                        textblok.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(textblok);
                        var radio = new RadioButton { Content = "Yes", GroupName = "userans", Name = "ansYes" + count };
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(radio);
                        var radio1 = new RadioButton { Content = "No", GroupName = "userans", Name = "ansNo" + count };
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(radio1);
                        var button = new Button { Content = "Submit", Name = "submitQuiz" };
                        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(getAnswer); 
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(button);
                        quizPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem { Name = "question" + count, Header = "Question " + count, Content = stackpanel });
                        //quesId.Text = o["questions"][i]["_id"].ToString();Click="Button_Click"

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
                        var textblok = new TextBlock { Text = o["questions"][i]["question"].ToString(), FontSize = 20, Width = 450 };
                        textblok.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(textblok);
                        var radio = new RadioButton { Content = "Yes", GroupName = "userans", Name = "useransYes" + count };
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(radio);
                        var radio1 = new RadioButton { Content = "No", GroupName = "userans", Name = "useransNo" + count };
                        stackpanel.Children.Add(radio1);
                        //, HorizontalAlignment = "Left", Margin = "66,317,0,0", VerticalAlignment = "Top
                        quizPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem { Name = "question" + count, Header = "Question " + count, Content = stackpanel });
                       // quesId.Text = o["questions"][i]["_id"].ToString();
                    }
                }
```

i am not sure how to get the values of the text block and check which radio button is checked. need help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access your dynamically created `TextBlock` and `RadioButton` this way :

```
//get stackpanel from the first pivot item
var pivotItem = (PivotItem)quizPivot.Items[0];
var stackpanel = (StackPanel)pivotItem.Content;
foreach(var control in stackpanel.Children)
{
    if(control is RadioButton)
    {
        var radio = (RadioButton)control;
        //do something with RadioButton
    }
    else if(control is TextBlock)
    {
        var textblok = (TextBlock)control;
        //do something with TextBlock
    }
}
```

Example above demonstrates on how to get controls from the first pivot item (`quizPivot.Items[0]`). That is basically reversed logic from what you did when creating those controls from C# code.

Comment: i have tried this code but it gives error on "Content". i tried to figure it out but failed. can you ??

Comment: updated my answer (not tested), please check if that fix the error.